# Received memory warning but the live bytes are only 5 to 10MB

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

i m developing and application as a universal application

when i run the application getting an received memory warning

i have used the profile to check the live bytes

but my live bytes never increase more that 5 to 10 MB

but still getting an received memory warning and app crashes

Comment: What is your app doing? Loading a gigantic high-resolution image?

Comment: Yes in my app i have to load heavy images. image resolution is 4524x3288 almost of 6 to 7MB

Comment: but i cant resize the image because i have to put the image on this area (4524x3288) of scroll view and user have to move the image in scroll area and find the objects

Comment: Are you loading multiple images or one single massive image? You still may need to shrink down the photo's resolution somewhat.

Comment: loading single image at a time

Comment: While your **compressed** 4524x3288 image may just be 6 to 7 MB, it will have to be uncompressed in memory. And uncompressed (assuming 8-bit RGB color plus probably a mandatory alpha channel) we are talking 4524x3288x4 bytes, which is nearly 60 MB. Handling that kind of memory requires very special care. You may have to tile it and work with smaller chunks.